# Problems with Lazysizes (Only dynamic img)

Tags: javascript, lazy-loading

I am implementing lazysizes and with static images it works perfectly for me, but when using it with dynamic images it doesn't work for me.

Lazysizes (https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes)

Works:

```
<img class="fade lazyload" data-src="{{asset('img/minus.png')}}"/>
```

Doesnt works:  (EDITED)

```
<div class="home-card-all">
                @foreach($product_all->product_images as $i=>$product_image_all)
                @if($i<1)
                <a href="{{route('product.detail', ['brand' => $product_all->brand, 'name' => $product_all->name])}}">
                    <img loading="lazy" id="image-{{$product_all->id}}" class="lazyload @if(count($product_all->stocks)>0) card-image @else card-image-no-stock @endif" data-src="{{url('product/'.$product_image_all->image)}}">
                    @endif
                    @endforeach
                    <h2>{{$product_all->brand . " ". str_replace('-', ' ', $product_all->name)}}</h2>
                    @if($product_all->discount>0 && count($product_all->stocks)>0)
                    <span><s>{{$product_all->price}} €</s></span>
                    <span class='discount'>-{{$product_all->discount}}%</span>
                    <p>{{\CountCartItem::calcPriceWithDiscount($product_all->id)}} €</p>
                    @else
                    <span></span>
                    <p>{{$product_all->price}} €</p>
                </a>
                @endif
                @if(count($product_all->stocks)==0)
                <span class='out-of-stock'>Out of stock</span>
                <p class="no-stock-product">No hay Stock!!</p>
                @endif
            </div>
```

Where is the problem?

(EDIT)

The code works and the images show them perfectly. What does not work is the library when trying to load the dynamic images through the foreach, when I load an image from asset it does work

Comment: What is _"lazysizes"_? What exactly isn't working?

Comment: Hi, sorry. Lazysizes (https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes) is a library for lazy images. Im asking because its not working with Dynamic images and i dont know how to fix it

Comment: Any errors in your browser console? Check the HTML source to see what image paths are being put into those `data-src` attributes and make sure they're correct. Check your _Network_ browser console to see what URLs are actually being requested.

Comment: Does `$product_image_all->image` actually return a valid URL?

Comment: Your `a` tag isn't closed in the loop (probably not the issue, but it could be _an_ issue)

Comment: Sorry, I did not write the link closure here but in my code it is closed. The images load perfectly, the fact is that the dynamic images do not accept them, I tried with static and if it works perfectly

Comment: @mylesthe.dev Yes, return the image